# Ticker jquery script not working correctly after 1st cycle

Tags: jquery

I have a script that shows the results of a processing page in a specific div and then iterates the results and displays each result one after the other. Each result is clickable and when clicked opens up another div to allow a response by users to the information given. The trouble I'm having is within the first cycle this works fine, but from the second cycle when the result is clicked it shows multiple instances of the same information. How can I clear all instances when the cycle has finished so the second cycle does exactly the same as the first cycle. the site is here [professor-sausage-fingers](http://www.professor-sausage-fingers.me.uk/)

after site has loaded there is a brief delay before the ticker starts working in the bottom right hand corner, after it works click on any of the questions in the first cycle and you will get a box pop up with the same question defined at the top of the popup box, this is exactly how I want it to work. Let the ticker run through the cycle of questions and start a second cycle, then click a question and in the pop up box you will see multiple definitions of the selected questions, which I don't want to happen. To clear the box the page will need to be refreshed.

The code used to create this function as follows:

```
    $.getJSON('includes/************.php', function(data)   { <!--jason call to listQuestions.php processing page-->

        $.each(data, function(key, val) { <!--iterate through the responce from the listQuestions.php processing page-->

        var QuestionID = val.Question_ID; <!--assign each Question_ID from the database to the variable QuestionID-->
        var Question = val.Question; <!--assign each Question from the database to the variable Question-->
        var QuestionInput = val.Question_ID; <!--assign each Question_ID from the database to the variable QuestionInput-->

console.log(QuestionID); <!--print out QuestionID in browser console for error checking purposes. Commented out in final code-->
console.log(Question);  <!--print out Question variable in browser console for error checking purposes. Commented out in final code-->

<!--start append html code into question results-->
$('#question_results_inner').append('<div id="questionNumber">Question '+ QuestionID +'</div>');
$('#question_results_inner').append('<div id="' + QuestionID + '" class="QuestionContent">'+ Question +'</div>');
$('#question_results_inner').append('<input type="button" id="'+ QuestionInput +'" class="QuestionAnswerButton" name="answerQuestion" value="Answer Question '+ QuestionID +'">');
<!--end append html code into question results-->

<!--start Add div dynamically into scrolling div-->
$('#scrollingDiv').append('<div id="scrollingDiv_inner_'+ QuestionID +'" class="scrollingDiv_Inner" style="display:none"><div id="questionNumber" class="scrollDivQuestNumber">Question '+ QuestionID +' </div><div id="' + QuestionID + '" class="QuestionContentScrollDiv">'+ Question +'</div></div>');
<!--end Add div dynamically into scrolling div-->


<!--starts the sliding function to show dynamically created div from database-->
function ticker() {

    $('#scrollingDiv .scrollingDiv_Inner:first').slideUp(function() {
        $(this).appendTo($('#scrollingDiv')).slideDown();

        $(this).click(function(event) {
    $("#answerQuestion").show("slow");
    $("#scrollingDiv").hide("slow");
    $("#scrollingDiv").empty();

    var txt = $(this).text();

    <!--alert (txt);-->

    $('#answerQuestion_inner').append('<div id="chosenQuestion" class="chosenQuestion"><div id="chosenQuestionTxt" class="chosenQuestiontxt">'+ txt +'</div></div>')



});

    });

}<!--end of the sliding function to show dynamically created dic from database-->

setInterval(function(){ ticker(); }, 5000); <!--sets the time interval in miliseconds for the ticker animation-->


        }); <!--end of iterate through the responce from the listQuestions.php processing page-->


    }); <!--end of jason call to listQuestions.php processing page-->
```

I believe this is the code that needs adjusting

```
function ticker() {

    $('#scrollingDiv .scrollingDiv_Inner:first').slideUp(function() {
        $(this).appendTo($('#scrollingDiv')).slideDown();

        $(this).click(function(event) {
    $("#answerQuestion").show("slow");
    $("#scrollingDiv").hide("slow");
    $("#scrollingDiv").empty();

    var txt = $(this).text();

    <!--alert (txt);-->

    $('#answerQuestion_inner').append('<div id="chosenQuestion" class="chosenQuestion"><div id="chosenQuestionTxt" class="chosenQuestiontxt">'+ txt +'</div></div>')
    });

    });

}
setInterval(function(){ ticker(); }, 5000);
```

and these lines specifically

```
$('#scrollingDiv .scrollingDiv_Inner:first').slideUp(function() {
    $(this).appendTo($('#scrollingDiv')).slideDown();
```

here I need to remove the question created so it isn't replicated in the next cycle or stop after the first cycle and refresh the function as if it is the first time the function runs. I have tried using `.show()` and `.hide()` also `.empty()` and `.remove()` but neither of these have worked, it may even be this is not the right way to do this, but I have found no other suggested code and I do not want to use a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

What I can see you are appending the same text multiple times. Try to put a if-statment and check the cycle like this:

```
function ticker() {
  var cycle = 0;
  $('#scrollingDiv .scrollingDiv_Inner:first').slideUp(function() {

    if (cycle < 1) {
      $(this).appendTo($('#scrollingDiv')).slideDown();

      $(this).click(function(event) {
        $("#answerQuestion").show("slow");
        $("#scrollingDiv").hide("slow");
        $("#scrollingDiv").empty();

        var txt = $(this).text();

        <!--alert (txt);-->

        $('#answerQuestion_inner').append('<div id="chosenQuestion" class="chosenQuestion"><div id="chosenQuestionTxt" class="chosenQuestiontxt">' + txt + '</div></div>')
      });
      cycle++;
    } else {
      $(this)..slideDown();
    }

  });

}
setInterval(function() {
  ticker();
}, 5000);
```

I am not 100% it will work, but it is a step in the right direction.